# How to format localized text in JSF

Tags: html, jsf, localization

I'd like to keep localized text in a **formatted** manner (Using the `<resource-bundle>` in `JSF`)

For example:

in `english.txt`:

```
welcome_msg = <p>Hello <b>Friend</b></p>
```

in `spanish.txt`:

```
welcome_msg = <p> Ola <b>Hombre</b> commo esta? </p>
```

(Just random examples)

If I just use `<h:outputText value="#{text.welcome_msg}" />` I will simply get the meta tags in the web page.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, [`<h:outputText/>`](http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/jsf-tags.html#Table4_11) escapes the `<`, `>`, and `&` characters. Use the `escape` attribute to disable this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{text.welcome_msg}" escape="false"/>
```

Be aware that this is now a potential security hole, depending on the source of the text that you are outputting.

See also: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html

Comment: I figured security would be a point to consider. In this case it is just translation text file on the server so no problem. Thanks!